# How to create a "Send to Mobile" button on web?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, facebook-social-plugins

I can see that Wooga and other developers started to include a button like this in their Facebook games, but can't find any references in the documentation.

There is an example of the button here: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/send_to_mobile.php?app_id=373748152681140&size=large and it sends a push notification to your Facebook app on your phone with a link to download the app from the appstore.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some Facebook test, they also do [this](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/08/09/facebook-looks-to-drive-app-installs-with-send-to-mobile-button-in-news-feed/). I don't think it's official yet

**Edit**: Also found code on [this](http://apps.facebook.com/slotscraze/) website:

```
<div id="toMobileOuter" style="position:absolute; top:2px; right:0px;">
            <iframe id="sendToMobile" frameborder="0" width="180px" height="24px"
                src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/send_to_mobile.php?app_id=460738653945219&size=medium"></iframe>
</div>
```